# Asp.Net Returning Custom Object in json

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a class CodeWithMessage that I want to return from my webservice as json.

The class is defined as such

```
namespace UserSite //Classes For my site
{
    namespace General
    {
        public class CodeWithMessage
        {
            private int iCode = 0;
            private string sMessage = "";
            public CodeWithMessage(int Code, string Message)
            {
                iCode = Code;
                sMessage = Message;
            }
            public CodeWithMessage()
            {
            }
            public void Message(string lMessage)
            {
                sMessage = lMessage;
            }
            public void Code(int lCode)
            {
                iCode = lCode;
            }
        }
```

In the Webservice I have

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Creates A New Blog.")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public CodeWithMessage AddNewBlog(string sTitle, string sDescription, string sOohrl, int iCategory=30)
    {
        CodeWithMessage CWM;
        CWM = new CodeWithMessage();
        CWM.Message("That url Is In Use");
        CWM.Code(0);
        return CWM;
```

I am posting the correct values (I truncated the function but it's getting what it needs and executing)
I get back

```
{"d":{"__type":"UserSite.General.CodeWithMessage"}}
```

I'm not sure why I am not getting back an actual json object with the values but rather just the class name??  I thought asp.net would automatically serialize the object? Does it not??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use public properties for the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to serialize the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) like you want.  The [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) cannot expose the methods nor the private fields.

```
namespace UserSite //Classes For my site
{
    namespace General
    {
        public class CodeWithMessage
        {         
            public int Code { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
     }
}

..............
//usage
CodeWithMessage CWM = new CodeWithMessage();
CWM.Message = "That url Is In Use";
CWM.Code = 0;
return CWM;
```